# accumulative css rule

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to write a javascript code that loads several css files. 
But link element has no onload event, that's why I append some extra element to my document wich tells me if css files have been loaded.
I wonder if there is a possibility to add only one element for all my css files and the same css rule.

In other words, is there an accumulative rule in css, i.e. the effect of it's application to dom element changes each time (i mean that the effect depends on how many times you applied this rule)?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc I need to get myself a dictionary...

Comment: @jeroen You can just google `define:grody`; it'll give you this: "nasty, dirty, disgusting, foul, revolting, yucky, grotesque"

Comment: @sdleihssirhc That's what I did :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such accumulative rule. You may add a class many times, but the element will look like if you did it once.

If you want control over loading you could load the css files directly into the page with ajax. The ajax request will give you response if if is completed. Now you can insert the css into the document and it will be applied immediately.

Using jQuery it could be

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url/to.css',
    dataType: text,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        $('body').append('<style>' + data + '</style>');
        // some more code as the css is in the page
    }
});
```

hope that helps a bit.

Comment: That will only work for inline css and not for external style-sheets.

Comment: This will tell you when the CSS has been completely sent by the server, but it won't tell you when that CSS has been parsed and applied, will it?

Comment: @jeroen: the external css file will be loaded by ajax and inserted as inline css. no problem or am I wrong? @sdleihssirhc: all browsers will apply the styles immediately.

Comment: I guess not, I was initially thinking about caching, but it shouldn't make a difference. I guess I just have an aversion against inline css, but I've never tried this. +1

Comment: I tried a quick example with a CSS file of 7000 plus lines, and then comparing `getComputedStyle`s. For some reason, once the CSS has been inlined by the JS, `getComputedStyle` appears to be broken... in Chrome at least. But in the course of trying to force it to work, it looked like the CSS *was* applied immediately.